# Is there a way to move files in azure file storage using only the rest APIs or python APIs

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-files

I was looking through the azure file service apis for python and for rest but I didn't see a method to just move files. I would like to move files on azure file storage without mounting a network drive is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, your requirement couldn't be implemented directly. However you could use the combination of `copy` and `delete` API.

These are [`copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/storageservices/copy-file) and [`delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/storageservices/delete-file2) API of REST.And this part is about [`copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure-storage-file/azure.storage.file.fileservice.fileservice?view=azure-python#copy-file) and [`delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure-storage-file/azure.storage.file.fileservice.fileservice?view=azure-python#delete-file) API of python.And an Azure Storage File is an SMB-compatible share, so you should be able to make files copies with normal file I/O operations.You could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39575240).

If this couldn't meet your requirement or still have questions, please let me know.

Comment: If my answer works ,could you accept my answer.Thanks.

Comment: You incur significant write costs if you do this though. But if it's the only way then it's the only way.